# how do i instantly update a value in appbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-appbar

I have a widget called 'HomePage' in my application. I gave a pageview to its body and put 2 pages in it. In the Appbar, there is a title that shows the user's money. on one of the pages there is a button that reduces money. but when I press this button the money is not updated immediately, if I change the page then it is updated. How do I immediately update the money value in the appbar without the page changing?

```
/////////////////// HOMEPAGE WİDGET ///////////////////

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/demo/user_infos.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(UserInfos.money.toString())),
      body: PageView(
        children: [
          Page1(),
          Page2(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///// UserInfo class//////

class UserInfos {
  static int money = 25000;
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////////// Page1()/////////////////////////////////


class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              UserInfos.money -= 1;
            });
          },
          child: const Text('decrease money')),
    );
  }
}
```

I also got help from chatgpt or something, but it didn't work. I need to change the page or do a hot reolad by doing 'ctrl+s'. only then the money value is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Calling [setState] notifies the framework that the internal state of
> this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface
> in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a [build] for
> this [State] object.

The key is rebuild your widgets tree everytime you change your widget' states

When you do like this

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  UserInfos userInfo;

  const Page1({super.key, required this.userInfo});

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() { // Page1 state changed, not homepage state
              widget.userInfo.money -= 1;
            });
          },
          child: const Text('decrease money')),
    );
  }
}
```

only page1 widget will be scheduled to rebuild. If you want to update changes to your homepage widget, you need to call `setState` inside your homepage widget

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  UserInfos _userInfo = new UserInfos();

  // setState here when userInfos changed

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(_userInfo.money.toString())),
      body: PageView(
        children: [
          Page1(userInfo: _userInfo),
          Page2(userInfo: _userInfo),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are many way to do this, the simplest is **callback**.

**Your HomePage widget:**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  void _updateState() {
    setState(() {
      UserInfo.money += 100;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(UserInfo.money.toString())),
      body: PageView(
        children: List.generate(
          3,
          (index) => Page(
            action: 'Action $index',
            onPressed: _updateState, // Pass your actions to child widget
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Your Page widget:**

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({
    super.key,
    required this.action,
    this.onPressed,
  });

  final String action;
  final Function()? onPressed;

  @override
  State<Page> createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: widget.onPressed, // Callback to change state
        child: Text(widget.action),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your `_updateState()` function is called inside HomePage widget, so it will rebuild your widget after state changed.

A better way is make your state **observable**

```
class UserInfo {
  // when you change money value, every listeners of this will be updated.
  static ValueNotifier<int> money = ValueNotifier(25000);
}
```

Update money value by

```
UserInfo.money.value = 100; // new value
```

And make your appbar listen for money value changes

```
AppBar(
  title: ValueListenableBuilder( // Your appbar will listen any UserInfo.money change
    valueListenable: UserInfo.money,
    builder: (context, value, child) => Text(value.toString()),
  ),
)
```

**Full solution**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: ValueListenableBuilder( // Your appbar will listen any UserInfo.money change
          valueListenable: UserInfo.money,
          builder: (context, value, child) => Text(value.toString()),
        ),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: List.generate(
          3,
          (index) => Page(
            action: 'Action $index',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserInfo {
  static ValueNotifier<int> money = ValueNotifier(25000);
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({
    super.key,
    required this.action,
  });

  final String action;

  @override
  State<Page> createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          UserInfo.money.value += 100;
        },
        child: Text(widget.action),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . I tried to do this for a long time but it didn't work. I learned something new thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not updating the appbar, because your setState() is called on a child widget, and rerender is top down not bottom up, so your child widget is never telling the parent to update.

I updated your code to pass an instance of your UserInfos class to each child that will manipulate it, so that they are updating the value directly. You should however make use of Providers, so that you can have the home widget listen to changes.

```
/////////////////// HOMEPAGE WİDGET ///////////////////

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/demo/user_infos.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  UserInfos _userInfo = new UserInfos();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(_userInfo.money.toString())),
      body: PageView(
        children: [
          Page1(userInfo: _userInfo),
          Page2(userInfo: _userInfo),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///// UserInfo class//////

class UserInfos {
  static int money = 25000;
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//////////// Page1()/////////////////////////////////


class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  UserInfos userInfo;

  const Page1({super.key, required this.userInfo});

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              widget.userInfo.money -= 1;
            });
          },
          child: const Text('decrease money')),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not understand proper your question

But as you said that when I press this button the money is not updated immediately, if I change the page then it is updated.

This is happened because

```
onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          UserInfos.money -= 1;
        });
},
```

your money value is updated but this setState() refresh only Page1 class UI tree.Not HomePage UI.So This is not reflected in your appbar.

If you immediately update the money value in the appbar without the page changing

try this saparate appbare code page1 class in pageview

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
const Page1({super.key});

@override
State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(UserInfos.money.toString())),
       body:Center(
         child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                 UserInfos.money -= 1;
               });
            },
           child: const Text('decrease money')),
      )
   );
  }
}
```

I hope this is useful.